How to convert a .bbx BibLaTeX style into a .csl file? (Citation Style Language)
I am using the BibLaTeX style verbose-trad1 but I could not find any file named verbose-trad1.csl into the huge CSL repository, while I need such a file to feed the pandoc --csl option.
pandoc -s main.tex --bibliography=bib.bib --citeproc --csl=verbose-trad1.csl -o main.docx

Finding a biblatex-to-csl converter would probably be the best option if available, and the most valuable for the community, but I have not found such a style converter yet. I did found bibliography file converters (like citation.js or biblatex-csl-converter), but no style file converter. Hence my question: does someone here know about such a style converter?
A little more context:

The source repository for verbose-trad1.bbx is available on CTAN.
And below is the exact LaTeX source code settings for my bibliography styling use case.

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=verbose-trad1,
  citepages=omit,
  citereset=chapter,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false,
  url=false,
  idemtracker=false,
  backref,backrefstyle=none
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
% Delete pagetotal field from every entry in bib file
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=pagetotal, null]
    }
  }
}


IMHO only 3 could be on-topic, the rest would be off-topic. But I don't know any bbx to csl converter and don't think, that there is any one. Note, that bbx files are TeX files and the macros are defined by biblatex. So IMHO the term "biber style" is somehow misleading. bbx files define the biblatex bibliography style (and cbx the biblatex citation style).

The "biber style" term was indeed misleading, so I changed it to BibLaTeX and .bbx where relevant, and also removed off-topic parts.

It is tricky to prove the non-existence of such a tool conclusively, but extensive online searches as well as my hunch say there is no such thing.
For one, there are already quite a few differences between the data formats for CSL and biblatex, see for example Citation Style Language (CSL), Citation Style Language vs. biblatex (vs. possibly other "citing-systems"?), https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/96906/create-bibtex-from-csl-file-individual-citation-style-from-my-university, and I'm pretty sure that there are CSL features for which biblatex does not have a simple equivalent and vice versa. But more importantly, biblatex styles can basically make use of all of (La)TeX, so any converter would have to understand all of LaTeX in order to generate an equivalent CSL - that seems pretty much impossible ("only TeX can parse TeX").
There isn't even a converter between BibTeX style files (.bst files) and biblatex style files (.bbx, .cbx files). These are two systems rooted in the TeX ecosystem and they are in some senses much closer than biblatex and CSL (then again, maybe not in some other senses). Yet still, no one has written a style converter for those two either.
Given that there has been a way to use .csl files in LaTeX since about 2021 (thanks to https://www.ctan.org/pkg/citation-style-language, see e.g. How can I use a CSL format in Overleaf or convert it to a BST?) a converter between CSL and biblatex seems even less worth the effort now.

+1 for everything
